# Может ли код апплета изменять значения HTML-тегов на web-страничке?

Tags: веб-программирование, applet, html, java

Хочу, чтобы при загрузке странички выполнялся апплет, который бы менял ссылки на этой страничке.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проще всего сделать код изменения ссылок на странице на JavaScript в виде функции и вызвать её из Java. Однако, если необходимо, то можно и из Java дотянуться до DOM-дерева, хотя это будет сложно и код будет ужасен.

В любом случае копайте в сторону JSObject и читайте [Java-to-Javascript Communication](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html). И ещё кучу всего по теме:

- [SO: Bridge between the Java applet and the text input controls on the web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014561/bridge-between-the-java-applet-and-the-text-input-controls-on-the-web-page)
- [видеоурок](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLsD1fqa4xs)
- [Calling methods of an Applet from JavaScript code](http://www.javareference.com/jrexamples/viewexample.jsp?id=81)
- [Google](https://www.google.ru/search?q=call+javascript+from+Java+applet&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:official&client=firefox)

Answer (score 0):

1. Да, может. Иначе в них было бы ещёменьше смысла, чем есть сейчас.
2. Джава-апплеты не только являются тяжеловесным и сомнительным решением, но и окончательно устарели. Начиная с Chrome 42 их использование ещё более затруднено и требует дополнительных действий от пользователя.
   https://www.java.com/ru/download/faq/chrome.xml
3. Всё что может быть сделано на js должно быть сделано на js безо всяких апплетов.